# Let $W_t$ be an one-dimensional Wiener process? Is $W_t$ bounded almost sure?

Tags: stochastic-processes

With the standard one dimensional Wiener process $W_t$? Is $P(\omega: \exists \mbox{ finite} \lim\limits_{t\to \infty}W_t(\omega))=1$?

Could you help me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The probability should be zero. I haven't actually checked computations but why would you expect BM to settle near a point?

Comment: Thanks Zachary Selk. Here, I want to know the boundedness of $W_t(\omega)$? Since I see some documents say that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{W_t}{t}=0$ almost sure. So, how does $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} W_t$?

Comment: $\limsup_{t \to \infty} W_t = \infty$ and $\liminf_{t \to \infty} W_t = - \infty$ almost surely, i.e. $W_t$ keeps oscillating.

Comment: Thanks Saz so much! However, could you tell me more details or could you give me a document concerning this? Thank you in advance!